# Excel table - selecting a column via =CONCATENATE()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am working on an excel spreadsheet.
In this spreadsheet I have a table called BenefitData.
This table has a number of columns made up of the month and year eg : 
Nov-2013-Benefits | Nov-2012-Benefits

What I would like to do is have the user select from a drop down the month then a year and then this give them the relevant benefits.

I am currently getting the data from the table like this :

BenefitData[Nov-2013-Benefits]

Is there a way of building up the column name. something like :

BenefitData[A1+"-"+A2+"-Benefits"]

I would like to do this without using VBA, Macros if possible

Kind Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer :

=INDIRECT("BenefitData["&A1&"]")

Thanks